# Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /var/www/html/cgi-bin/check.cgi

Tags: perl, taint

I have a little cgi script running on a Apache 2.4.57

I am trying to exec a php file in the script like this

```
exec ('php /var/www/html/footer.php') or print STDERR "couldn't exec $command: $!";
```

But it didn't work out. The apache log throws the error

> Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /var/www/html/cgi-bin/check.cgi"

How can add `$ENV{'PATH'}` to make it secured?

Comment: I have added $ENV{PATH} = '/bin:/usr/bin'; before the exec like this and it is no longer complaining. 

$ENV{PATH} = '/bin:/usr/bin';
exec ('php /var/www/html/footer.php') or print STDERR "couldn't exec $command: $!";

But the CSS, bootstrap in the php file couldn't load up.

Any idea please.

Comment: The reason you are getting this error is that your script has a security feature enabled that does not allow you to use unsafe data sources. This is described in perldoc perlsec. You can untaint variables to make them usable.

Answer (score 2):

> How can add $ENV{'PATH'} to make it secured?

Set it to a defined value, i.e.

```
$ENV{PATH}="/bin:/usr/bin";
```

And better call your script with full path so that it does not need to rely on PATH. Also don't use the shell to interpret the command line but use the multi-argument form to directly invoke the program:

```
exec ('/usr/bin/php', '/var/www/html/footer.php') or ...
```

Comment: Thanks Steffen. 

exec ('/usr/bin/php', '//var/www/html/footer.php');

Same error - Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch

Comment: @luchris: see updated answer

Comment: Hi i did that before your answer. The JS, CSS etc wont run up. Anyway i use definite paths instead and all working now.

Answer (score 0):

$ENV{PATH} = '/bin:/usr/bin'; before the exec like this and it is no longer complaining. $ENV{PATH} = '/bin:/usr/bin'; exec ('php /var/www/html/footer.php') or print STDERR "couldn't exec $command: $!";

"But the CSS, bootstrap in the php file couldn't load up. Any idea please."

As for the CSS, JS, bootstrap, i just use direct paths instead of https:// and all working now. Thank you